# Set cell value with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, wia

I scan and save images with Wia using VBA in Microsoft Access.

The filepath to the saved image should be set as the value of the current cell.

I can't figure out how to do this but it seems like an easy task after learning how to use Wia.

Here is my current code that scans a document.

```
Function scanImage() As String
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim folder As String
    folder = "C:\Users\username\Pictures\scans\"
    Dim tempName, obj
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    tempName = obj.GetTempName
    Dim filename
    filename = Now
    filename = Replace(filename, ".", "_")
    filename = Replace(filename, " ", "_")
    filename = Replace(filename, ":", "_")
    imagePath = folder & filename & ".jpg"

    Dim dev As Device
    Dim wiaDialog As New WIA.CommonDialog
    Dim wiaImage As WIA.ImageFile
    Set dev = wiaDialog.ShowSelectDevice
    Set wiaImage = wiaDialog.ShowAcquireImage
    wiaImage.SaveFile (imagePath)
    scanImage = imagePath

End Function
```

Comment: there is no 'cell' in Access

Comment: Well, I can create database columns at set values for 'cells'.
How do I access and manipulate a 'database entry' if that's the correct vocabulary? :)

Comment: There's a lot to learn for you - too much to write here. You really should browse for a beginner's tutorial and work through the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments have said - there's no cells in Access, and definitely no active cell.
You can add a record to a database using either of the methods below, but how do you plan on extracting that information again?

In Excel you just ask for the data in cell A1 for example, but in a database you generally ask for the data from a field or fields where another field on that same record is equal to some other values (either by supplying the 'other value' directly or by referencing other tables within the database).

So, for example, in your database you'd ask for the file paths of all files scanned on a certain date, or have some kind of description field to identify the file.
This would be written something like:
`SELECT FilePath FROM Table2 WHERE DescriptionField = 'MyPhoto'`

Anyway, the answer to get that single text string (imagepath) into a new record in a table is:

```
Sub InsertValueToTable()

    Dim imagepath As String

    imagepath = "<file path>"

    'NB:  The table name is 'Table2', the field (column) within the table is called 'FilePath'.

    'One way to do it:
    'DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table2(FilePath) VALUES ('" & imagepath & "')"

    'Another way to do it:
    Dim rst As dao.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table2")
    With rst
        .AddNew
        rst!FilePath = imagepath
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note - if you use a `Text` field in the database you'll be limited to 255 characters.

Comment: Thank you! DAO was everything I needed to hear. Looks like I googled wrong :)